# jQuery Selectors and IFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would appreciate some assistance with the following:

I have three forms inside of three iframes with three buttons in the common parent page. The onclick event of the buttons needs to submit the forms in the iframes.

The iframes are dynamically instantiated into the parent page through JavaScript, however I don't think that really matters.

There are three div tags that are used to draw the iframes: div-1 div-2 div-3.
None of the forms have an id. However, all three forms share the same name attribute "rdForm".

What selector would be employed to submit each form in an onclick button event? Or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: Select the iframe, get it's document `$(theiframe).contents()` then find your forms and submit them `.find('form[name=foobar]').submit()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the frames :

```
<input type="button" class="submit" data-iframe="iframe_name_1" value="Submit" />
<input type="button" class="submit" data-iframe="iframe_name_2" value="Submit" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('.submit').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var iframename = $(this).data('iframe');
            window.top['iframename'].document.rdForm.submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```